# Get Google token in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-authentication, access-token

How do I get google id token and access token for Firebase?

I need them here:

```
  Firebase.Auth.Credential credential =
         Firebase.Auth.GoogleAuthProvider.GetCredential(googleIdToken, googleAccessToken);
```

I tried to get token like this:

```
 PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetToken();
```

But it returns null. Please help.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41779109/3785314) solution  and let me know if that works.

Comment: Did you get the solution?